# line break <hr> not rendering as expected

Tags: html, css

Any idea why there's a thin grey line above my green

---

and how to get rid of it?

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7gym88/

[image]

```
hr {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #469551;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  height: 0;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm asking because I don't see it on latest FireFox

Comment: I would have had the same question as @CupofJava. No line in Chrome or Safari either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
border-bottom: 4px solid #469551;
```

by this:

```
 border: 4px solid #469551;
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/okbrf9f0/)

Answer (score 4):

It's because `<hr/>` has border (at least in FireFox since `<hr/>` has browser dependent style).

Remove border first.

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #469551;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  height: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Removed default `<hr>` border and uses height and background

```
hr {
  background: #469551;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  height: 4px;
  border:none;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7gym88/1/

Answer (score 1):

by default tag `<hr>` taking border so you need first border zero. then add height check my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7gym88/2/)